# Is there a SASS function that gets equivalent property percentage value?

Tags: javascript, css, function, sass

Is there a SASS function or something similar that gets the equivalent width property value of an element that's already been set to percentage?

Something like: `function get-property-value($selector, $property);`

code:

```
 div#test {
  width: 35%;
 }
 p {
  left: calc(50% - get-property-value('div#test', 'width'));    
 }
```

if there is none, what's the best solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: no there isn't, if you want to calculate width, you should write function and pass your width , but if the width is diffrent in your other file you can use variable and set it as a default variable like  $testwidth: 30px !default; and set other width in your diffrent sass file

Comment: Thank you for this information, very much appreciated...